# I wrote a simple code to find GCD of two numbers and i tried for 3 values (3, 12), (35, 24), (24,12)

Tags: python

The below code returns None for value(35, 24) can anyone suggest why instead of 1 it is displaying None while it is working fine for other values?

I have tried with the below solution

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a < b:
        if b % a == 0:
            return a
        else:
            gcd(a, b % a)
    elif a > b:
        if a % b == 0:
            return b
        else:
            gcd(b, a % b)

print gcd(35, 24)
```

I expect the output  to be 1, but the actual output is None

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `return` in your recursive calls. For example,

```
gcd(a, b % a)
```

should be:

```
return gcd(a, b % a)
```

You also have an issue that you don't return anything when `a == b`. Since when `a == b` neither `a < b` or `a > b` is true. Can you solve that?